# Obtaining 15 V from a single lithium polymer cell

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply

I want to get 15V output from a  1 cell lithium polymer battery which has a voltage range of 3v-4v.  I am thinking about using a [34063](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00001232.pdf) to accomplish this.  But will this work over a 1v range or do I need a different ic?

edit:
I want to get around 250mA

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your 15 V rail power?

Answer (score 4):

The 1V range from 3-4V isn't the problem.  The IC regulates by comparing the output voltage with an internal reference voltage, so as long as the input stays within spec (some unpublished minimum voltage to a max of 50V) and below your desired Vout (this isn't a buck/boost converter), you should be fine.  It's the minimum voltage requirements are worrying.  Your desired operation from a single coin cell is really a special application, and, as Madmanguruman said, it looks like this IC was made for much less imaginative applications - boosting a 5V supply.

Since your users might be tempted to stick in an alkaline battery or a dead battery, why not use something that's designed to work with a lower voltages? Linear Technology's [LT1308](http://www.linear.com/pc/productDetail.jsp?navId=H0,C1,C1042,P1627) switcher will work down to 1V, and has a switch current of up to 3A, so you should be able to get 15V at 250mA out of it.

(Disclaimer: I like Linear products; I go to their site first to look up stuff like this.  I didn't compare with other manufacturers, but you should.)

Comment: I am using a lithium polymer pack, no chance of them sticking a battery in that.  Also part you linked to seems to boost to 3.3v I am trying to get to 15v from 3v-4v

Comment: I think the maximum voltage boost you could get out of the LT1307 is about 4x; as the SW duty cycle tops out at about 75%.

Comment: A pack?  Sorry, I misread your question - my brain said 'coin'.  However, you're incorrect about the 3V3 output- The part is configured with a resistor divider connected to the FB pin, the voltage is Vout = 1.22*(1+R1/R2).  The example circuit shows the use of a 1.02M and 604k resistor to get 3.3V, you could set these values to, for example, 920k and 87k to get 15.6V.

Comment: @reem: Am I reading the maximum duty cycle wrong?  I don't think you can endlessly increase the voltage by just adjusting the feedback divider; there's a maximum multiplication you can get out of it.  The max SW current * input voltage will also limit the power you can kick out.

Comment: @Nick - With respect to the maximum power, the OP was working with a 3-4V battery, and the switch current has a normal maximum of 600mA.  If the battery was discharged, 3V*.6A*(3/15 current division)*75% efficiency is about 270mA, which is about what the OP wanted.  600mA is probably more than the battery pack can sustain anyways.  If they need more, they'll need to move away from the single-cell oriented supplies to something more powerful, possibly with an external switch.

Comment: @Nick - With respect to the current, you're right, for a simple converter the output voltage is limited by the duty cycle to Vo/Vin = 1/(1-D), or about 12V in this case. However, other topologies can increase the voltage further.  The datasheet has schematics for converters with Vout=16-24V, Vout up to 85V (!), and capacitor doublers and tripplers that extend the maximum voltage even higher.  These will all decrease the current available, so I've edited my part number from the LT1307 to the LT1308 :)

Answer (score 2):

A big concern is that the datasheet you described characterizes many of the crucial parameters at VCC=5V. You may find that getting the performance you want could be tricky, and part-to-part variations could play a big role. You'll need to prototype the circuit and test in the 3-4V range (and also most likely below 3V) to see what you're getting yourself into.

Answer (score 2):

See figure 12. Output current is not specified for input voltages under 5v, but if you need few hundreds milliamps it might be fine.

I would looks for another dc-dc, with higher switching speed & efficiency >80%. Anyway, using such a high-voltage chip for 3-4v power source is just a waste of silicon.

Comment: Why does he need higher efficiency?

Comment: erm figure 12 refers to the test setup where Vcc is targeted at 5v, this is a configurable boost regulator.

Comment: @reemrevnivek He might not needed, but as efficiency is not stated anywhere, it might be quite horrible.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be a PoL (Point of Load) converter such as [TI's PTN04050C 12-W, 3.3/5-V Input, Wide Adjust Output Boost Converter](http://focus.ti.com/docs/prod/folders/print/ptn04050c.html).  However that is almost a 1 A part and so overkill.  If I were cost- or area-sensative I might try [TI's TPS61085](http://focus.ti.com/docs/prod/folders/print/tps61085.html).